# Besides of photon, what else can excite electron from valence band to conduction band, then to form exciton?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, atomic-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

The title is my question. Besides of photon, what else can excite electron from valence band to conduction band, then to form exciton? thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In principle, any of the processes that lead to exciton relaxation (i.e., finite time of exciton and electron-hole pairs) can also happen in reverse direction and create an exciton. However, most of these processes are too difficult to use in practice.

- One could cite here *Auger scattering*, that is collision with other electrons, notably an electron already excited to a higher energy band, in which case it could transfer to a valence electron an energy close to that of the gap, i.e., sufficient for creating an exciton.
- Another option is a multiphonon process, where several (likely optical) phonons may have sufficient energy for creating an electron-hole pair.

Another possibility is using a semiconductor device, in a geometry similar to a semiconductor laser/photodiode - in this case electrons and hole are injected in the active region from adjacent regions enriched in only one type of carriers (p-/n-regions). The difference is that in lasers and photodiodes the electron-hole pairs are strongly coupled to the electromagnetic field - we do not want them to become excitons, since this would broaden the line, i.e., reduce the quality of the laser. However, one can envision opposite conditions, where the radiative transitions are suppressed, and the gas of electron-hole gradually cools down to form excitons.

The literature on the Bose-Einstein condensation of excitons (a popular subject about a decade and a half ago) might contain many ideas along these lines.

Comment: many thanks for the info. From a view of experiment, only light can exciton the transfer of e- from VB to CB? excuse me, my background is medicine.

Comment: I think exciting by light is the most used - it has the advantage that one can create directly excitons, rather than just e-h pairs - by tuning the frequency a bit below the bandgap, to the exciton resonance. One option for transferring electrons from valence to conduction band, that I forgot to mention in my answer, is [Zener effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_effect)

Comment: If I send an energetic charged particle (electron or ion) into the semiconductor that will generate e-h pairs quite readily.

Comment: @RogerVadim I see. I want to do in vivo PL imaging, say, excite gap-material inside body. light of long-wavelength can easily pass through skin and muscle, but with low energy. I wonder is there applied field (magnetic or electrical field) can excite the electron? First I know MRI use radio-frequency (RF) to excite. But it is nuclei which RF pulse excites, not electron........

Comment: There is more 2 and 3 photon imaging being done now. There the lower energy photons add their energy though a nonlinear process. That might be something for you to read about. But in biology the use of fluorphores or attaching molecules to proteins is how a lot of imaging is being done.

Comment: Really nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple answer might be that *any* particle which carries energy and has a nonzero cross-section for electrons (which I believe is theoretically true for any particle) could possibly collide/interact with an electron and transfer the energy required to raise the orbital level.   Photons turn out to be the easiest to generate and control.
I see a few comments related to applying RF fields, which after all are just a flux of very long-wavelength photons.  While NMR, "nuclear magnetic resonance," scanners function by finding resonant frequencies within atoms [note: I still hate the anti-panic renaming as "Magnetic Resonance Imaging"] ,  I'm not sure that attempting resonant absorption in electrons is possible. Certainly it'd take a very large-multi-photon absorption event to bump up the orbital.